# router outlet is not rendering

Tags: angular, typescript

my project folder structure like below

```
|-- app
     |-- home
       |-- home-page
           |--home-page.component.css
           |--home-page.component.html
           |--home-page.component.spec.ts
           |--home-page.component.ts
       |-- login
           |--home-page.component.css
           |--home-page.component.html
           |--home-page.component.spec.ts
           |--home-page.component.ts
       |-- user-profile
           |--user-profile.component.css
           |--user-profile.component.html
           |--user-profile.component.spec.ts
           |--user-profile.component.ts
     |-- home-routing.module.ts
     |-- home.module.spec.ts
     |-- home.module.ts
|-- app-routing.module.ts
|-- app.component.css
|-- app.component.html
|-- app.component.ts
|-- app.module.ts
```

my `home-routing.module.ts` consisting like below

```
export const HomeRoutingModule: Routes = [
    {
        path: "user-profile",
        children: [
            {
                path: "user-profile",
                component:UserProfileComponent ,
                data: {
                    title: "user-profile",
                    urls: [{ title: "user-profile", url: "user-profile" }]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

and `app-routing.module.ts` is like below

```
  { path: "home", component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: "user-profile",
    component: HomePageComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "user-profile", loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule" },
    ]
  }
```

now I'm trying to render `user-profile.components.html` inside the `home-page.component.html`for that i tried to add the sample code snippet in the home-page.component.ts like below

```
<p>this is header</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<p>this is footer</p>
```

my url is like below [localhost:4200/#/user-profile](http://localhost:4200/#/user-profile), but it is rendering only below output except  content

```
this is header

this is footer
```

I think something I missed, Even I'm not able to figure out that . Could any one point out, whats went wrong in this code .

**Edit:**
home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(HomeRoutingModule),
    HomeRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [UserProfileComponent, HomePageComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Comment: you have the same path for all the components . I think router is unable to detect which component to be loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with deep nesting of your path `/user-profile/user-profile`. You should use the path only once.

#### Modified version of your routing

> app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: "home", component: LoginComponent },
{
    path: "user-profile",
    component: HomePageComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "", loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule" },
    ]
  }
```

> home-routing.module.ts

```
export const HomeRoutingModule: Routes = [
    {

                path: "",
                component:UserProfileComponent ,
                data: {
                    title: "user-profile",
                    urls: [{ title: "user-profile", url: "user-profile" }]
                }
    }
];
```

### Edit

Remove `HomeRoutingModule` from imports.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(HomeRoutingModule)
  ],
  declarations: [UserProfileComponent, HomePageComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Comment: Just simplified your routing configuration. Please check the answer.

Comment: @SunilSingh this should work fine as his ``HomePageComponent`` is never loaded unless the whole module is loaded looking at the question .

Comment: @CruelEngine - then path must be left blank for children as updated in the answer.

Comment: @SunilSingh yes so when the path is ``""``, the module should be loaded or when path is ``user-profile`` module should be loaded  , and the internal routes should be handled inside the module

Comment: @changeneed - did you miss the `<routing-outlet>` in `app.component.html` ?

Comment: I tried your answer but throwing error`Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'HomeModule'
Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'HomeModule'`

Comment: Share `home.module.ts`

Comment: I have added `home.module.ts` please check it

Comment: Remove `HomeRoutingModule` from `imports`. Updated the anwser.

Comment: @SunilSingh you cannot pass a Module to ``RouterModule.forChild()`` as you can pass only variable of type ``Routes``

Comment: Correct. however here `HomeRoutingModule` not module instead a `constant` variable named as `HomeRoutingModule`. Look at the code again.

Comment: `export const HomeRoutingModule: Routes =`

Comment: @SunilSingh my bad looks like i got confused with the naming of variable .

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your `home-routing.module.ts` as :

```
    export const HomeRoutingModule: Routes = [
{path : "" , component : HomePageComponent},
        {
                    path: "user-profile",
                    component:UserProfileComponent ,
                    data: {
                        title: "user-profile",
                        urls: [{ title: "user-profile", url: "user-profile" }]
                    }
                }
    ];
```

and `app-routing.module.ts` as :

```
  { path: "home", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "", loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule"} ,
```

and your router should work fine i.e `/` will load `HomeComponent` and `user-profile` will load `UserProfileComponent`.

**EDIT**

There is an error in your `home-routing.module,ts` :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [UserProfileComponent, HomePageComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

You remove `RouterModule.forChild(HomeRoutingModule)`from `imports`

Comment: can you try now ? i made an edit as there was a line i missed(didn't understand) in your question

Comment: @changeneed you have ``a router-outlet`` in your ``HomePageComponent`` right ?

Comment: yes I have router outlet in my homepagecomonent only

Comment: I tried your answer but throwing error`Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'HomeModule' Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'HomeModule'`

Comment: @changeneed can you post the ``home.module.ts `` as per the error there is some issue in your module

Comment: I have added `home.module.ts` please check it

Comment: @changeneed please move your ``LoginComponent`` from your ``HomeModule`` to ``/app`` you'll have your ``/login`` will also start working

Answer (score 0):

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
    { path: "home", component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: "user-profile",
    component: HomePageComponent,
    loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule"
  }
```

**home-routing.module.ts**

```
export const HomeRoutingModule: Routes = [
    {

                path: "",
                component:UserProfileComponent ,
                data: {
                    title: "user-profile",
                    urls: [{ title: "user-profile", url: "user-profile" }]
                }
    }
];
```

Comment: I tried your answer but throwing error`Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'HomeModule' Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'HomeModule'`